# How do you use React Native hooks correctly?

Tags: react-native, react-hooks

I am trying to learn how to use React Native hooks and create reusable components once I call GetPlayer, nothing appears on my screen when running my code and I am not getting any exceptions in my Console.

Am I calling the GetPlayer component correctly or is there something I am missing? thanks

App.js File below

```
import { StatusBar } from 'expo-status-bar';
import { StyleSheet, Text, View } from 'react-native';
import GetPlayer from './GetPlayer';

export default function App() {
  return (
    <View style={styles.container}>
      <Text>Open up App.js to start working on your app!</Text>
         <GetPlayer /> 
      <StatusBar style="auto" />
    </View>
  );
}
const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    backgroundColor: '#fff',
    alignItems: 'center',
    justifyContent: 'center',
  },
});
```

- 

GetPlayer.js file

```
import { View } from "react-native-web"


export default function GetPlayer(){
    return (
        <View style={styles.container}>
            <Text>Test </Text>
        </View>
    )
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
    container: {
      flex: 1,
      backgroundColor: '#fff',
      alignItems: 'center',
      justifyContent: 'center',
    },
  });
```

Image of folder

[image]

Comment: try to define the component and then export it. `function GetPlayer(){.....}` and at the end `export default GetPlayer`

Comment: Did you intend to import View from `react-native-web` in GetPlayer? Seems like you might want the `react-native` one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> You need to add import Text component in order to write something
> on screen just like this

```
import { View } from "react-native-web"
import { StyleSheet, Text } from 'react-native';


export default function GetPlayer(){
    return (
        <View >
            <Text>Tesdkasjdnb </Text>
        </View>
    )
}
```

Comment: hmmm doesn't seem to be working still , with this edit

Comment: you can check this Expo link 
https://snack.expo.dev/@abdullahrishi1999/getplayer

Comment: ok working now , i honestly dunno why it didnt work for me i just copied from your expo link there now  it works . thanks for your help

Answer (score 0):

In GetPlayer.js file try below imports and Text component is also not imported

```
import { Text, View } from 'react-native';
```

Comment: yes tried this also , same issue

Answer (score 0):

Try making changes to the **`flex:1`** style in App.js and I think you don't need to apply `flex:1` in GetPlayer.js also.